# Jhipster: application is running but no output on the browser

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, jhipster

After installing Jhipster and getting my application running using **yarn**, the application is running on terminal but on my browser nothing apears, there's an error message in the Console which is the following:

```
ERROR Error: The selector "jhi-main" did not match any elements
    at DefaultDomRenderer2.selectRootElement (platform-browser.es5.js?41b7:2791)
    at DebugRenderer2.selectRootElement (core.es5.js?de3d:13633)
    at createElement (core.es5.js?de3d:9172)
    at createViewNodes (core.es5.js?de3d:12146)
    at createRootView (core.es5.js?de3d:12075)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.es5.js?de3d:13458)
    at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (core.es5.js?de3d:12775)
    at ComponentFactory_.create (core.es5.js?de3d:9858)
    at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create (core.es5.js?de3d:3333)
    at ApplicationRef_.bootstrap (core.es5.js?de3d:4763)
```

What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your index.html file.
src->main->webapp->index.html

```
<jhi-main></jhi-main>
```

[screenshot from my workspace / index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbgm2.png)